# Iphone:Youtube video in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiwebview, youtube

I Want to show the the youtube video in an `UIWebView` and I am able to show the Video in an `UIWebView` with the help of following function to embed the YouTube URL.

```
  - (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url
{

    NSString *embedHTML = @"<html><head><meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width =\"%0.0f\"/></head><body style=\"background:transparent;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px\"><div><object width=\"212\" height=\"172\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"%@\"></param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></object></div></body></html>";


    //NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, self.videoView.frame.size.width, self.videoView.frame.size.height];

    NSString *html=[NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,self.videoView.frame.size.width,url,url,self.videoView.frame.size.width,self.videoView.frame.size.height];


    [self.videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

Here url is the youtube url,videoView is the webview.
Now this function works just good for the normal urls like http://www.youtube.com....  but for the mobile youtube urls like http://m.youtube.com.... ,it doesn't show the video, though the video can be played on the browser.
It is working if I replace the 'm' with 'www' from the url,but I dont think so it is good idea.

Comment: encode the url using NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: @karthika no it's not working with the encoded url as well